# How to consolidate two huge data sources to one list and support pagination?

Tags: java, list, pagination, aggregate

I have two data sources containing elements of the same entity. And I want to combine them in a single list. The amount of data is too much to just query everything from both sources to combine them.
The displayed data at a time should be of a given page size, so pagination needs to be supported

Is this possible without querying everything and putting a filter on the combined list?

Comment: In theory I'd probably read 1 page from each source (sorted of course) and combine/interleave those. In the worst case the page you'd return contains only elements from one of the data sources that's why you need a page from each - you don't know the result until you've loaded them. The returned page might also need to contain formation where the "next" page in each of the datasources would start as you don't want to skip any records.

Answer (score 0):

you can use google guava's `Iterators.mergeSorted()` utility function. it takes as inputs:

- a collection of iterators that retrieve the data to be combined
- a comparator

the only constraint is that the input iterators need to provide the data in non-descending order. Pagination can be achieved by skipping pageNr x pageSize elements before returning data.